# How can I check if a user's input is both valid and also a number I'm looking for?

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements

How could I create a conditional statement that prevents entering the fail state, and asks the user for new data when either the data is invalid or the data is not 1, 2, 3 OR 4 ?

```
int choice;

while ( !choice || choice != 1 || 2 || 3 || 4){
     cout << "Entry Invalid. Enter again: ";
     cin >> choice
}
```

For example, If the user enters 'f', then the fail state would be taken care of, and the program would ask for new data. And when they enter 5, the program would say "Not a valid number", and ask for new data.

Comment: Read input as a character (or string - a set of characters).  If that succeeds, check if it represents valid input (e.g. a set of digits).      Get out of the habit of from trying to check multiple values using construct like `choice != 1 || 2 || 3 || 4` because that does not do anything like what you seek - read any basic textbook on C++ to understand both what that construct does and what you actually need to do.

Answer (score 0):

For `stoi` you need C++11 standard

```
int choice;
string inp;

cin >> inp;

while(inp != "1" && inp != "2" && inp !="3" && inp !="4"){

    cout << "Wrong input , type again" << endl;
    //system("PAUSE");
    cin >> inp;

}
choice = stoi(inp);
cout << choice;
```

Answer (score 0):

This exact problem caused me way too much trouble in first year. This should do what you want, maybe try implementing a maximum number of failed attempts.

```
int choice = 0;
while (true) {
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 4" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else if (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
        cout << "Not a valid number" << endl;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
cout << "You chose " << choice << endl;
```